# iOS - static cells not appearing in a subclass of UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know that static are working only with `UITableViewController`. So I did drag&drop `UITableViewController` in storyboard to my working space. I added some static cells and they are working fine when I run my app. But if I change the class (in Storyboard) to my own subclass of `UITableViewController` - static cells disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you implementing the tableViewDataSource methods in your subclass?

Comment: Please post your UITableViewController subclass code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it out. When you create a subclass of `UITableViewController` Xcode automatically creates methods which override static cells data. So you have to comment these out:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```